# Send Form Object as Reference to Method

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, this

When I need to process a form, I usually send a reference of the form to the function using

```
<input type='submit' onclick='validateForm(this.form)'>
```

However, in this case my form exists inside of an iFrame and when I pass 'this' I get a reference to the iFrame.  How do I pass the form reference inside of the iFrame?